# The origin for the sensor is out of map bounds

Tags: ros, navigation, sensor, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i launch move_base for navigation stack it gives:

> **[WARN]** [1436954622.771961072]: The origin for the sensor at (0.17, -0.19) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.

The tf_tree is normal:

> 

At time 1436956287.222

- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.035]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
  in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
  in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]

> 

At time 1436956288.221

- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.035]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
  in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
  in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]

The size of costmap is 100x100.
Footprint is  [ [-0.113, 0.123],[0.113, 0.123],[0.113, -0.123], [-0.113, -0.123] ]
The param "rolling_window" is true.
In RVIZ costmap is in [bounds](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=9f71e28d54cee76954a68e87096437de) (grey square). It also seems me a strange

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213771/the-origin-for-the-sensor-is-out-of-map-bounds/) by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Double check the origin parameters for the costmap. For a local costmap that's 10m square, you'd often set them to -5.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on 2015-07-15**:
I didn't change them, so they are zeros (x and y origin). Ok, i will assign a -5 its.